# How to find correct horizontal and vertical offset of an element?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, selenium

I am currently using Selenium and Ruby. My question is what to pass to move_by method of Selenium Web Driver?

```
#move_by(right_by, down_by, device: nil) ⇒ W3CActionBuilder
driver.action.move_by(100, 100).perform
```

The [document](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/PointerActions#move_by-instance_method) says this:

Parameters:

- right_by (Integer) — horizontal offset. A negative value means moving
  the mouse left.
- down_by (Integer) — vertical offset. A negative value means moving
  the mouse up.
- device (Symbol || String) — optional name of the PointerInput device
  to move

So I went and found the DOMRect of the element using Chrom Dev tools and ran this command in console:

```
$0.getBoundingClientRect()
```

Which returns these values:

```
bottom: 410
height: 14
left: 1801.65625
right: 1817.65625
top: 396
width: 16
x: 1801.65625
y: 396
```

So, the question is what is my right_by and down_by parameters from the numbers above?

Comment: So having located the element you want to move to, is there some reason you are using the **move_by()** rather than **move_to(element)**

Comment: `x` = `right_by` and `y` = `down-by`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript to scroll to the desired position.
Javascript:

```
window.scrollTo(100,100);
```

Calling Javascript in ruby:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(1801.65625,396);")
```

Alternatively you can use `scroll.to` if you are trying to scroll to an element, just in case.

```
driver.element().scroll.to :bottom
```

Comment: So what is my 100, 100 ? Based on the numbers I provided?

Comment: updated the answer with x,y values from your question. Also check the other option to scroll to element if you are working on element rather on the browser itself.

Comment: driver.element().scroll.to :bottom is this a ruby syntax?

Comment: Yes. `driver.element(xpath: "xpath goes here").scroll.to :bottom`

Comment: I'm getting an error: Minitest::UnexpectedError: NoMethodError: undefined method `element' for

Comment: Sorry, my bad the previous syntax will work only if you are using [cheezy_page_object] (https://www.rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object). Here is the generic `driver.find_element(xpath: "xpath goes here").scroll.to :bottom`

Comment: Yeah I am not using that library. So I dont have the scroll method

Comment: I am using the javascript executor to scroll to an element, script = ('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', element) but this script only works in chrome and not in IE.Therefore, in IE I am not scrolling to my element which causing the failure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190057/discussion-between-supputuri-and-hashim77).

Comment: Checheked `document.querySelector("a[href='microsoft-edge:http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftEdgeWelcome']").scrollIntoView(true)` in IE console and working as expected. Make sure you are passing the right element.